# Number of balls touching one ball at the center.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, reference-request, terminology

Let $B$ be a ball of radius one in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I'm looking for references about the following problem :

How many **disjoint** balls $B_i$ of radius one is it possible to put in contact (tangential contact) to the ball $B$ ?

For example, if $d=2$, we can put a maximum of $6$ balls touching $B$ (each $B_i$ will then be in contact with $B$ + two other neighbor balls, see picture below).

I found out that this problem is linked to the question of "compact arrangement of balls" arising in physics and chemistry (especially in crystallography), but I don't know the classic references for a mathematical approach. Does this problem have a mathematical name ? Do you have references to share ?

Any help is welcomed, please feel free to re-tag as appropriate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the [kissing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number).